# Bash shell script on system start macOS

Tags: bash, macos, daemon

I know that I can use plist like this one

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.exampled</string>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
        <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>absolute_path_to_script</string>

    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But it runs from shell, not bash
What can I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `<string>/bin/sh</string>` to `<string>/bin/bash</string>`.

Comment: Thx, you really helped

Comment: Welcome. Please accept the answer if it solved your issue. Thanks.